# worklight android push notification device settings?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating push notification for Android & IOS by using Worklight. 
If the user manually changes the push notification settings in mobile, how to get the action/value in worklight.

When the user switch-on/off the notification then how to handle the action in Worklight?

Any code help please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the state of these controls, at least in the case of iOS, by querying UIApplication > [enabledRemoteNotificationTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (you will likely need to [create a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid) to access this using Objective-C).

In Android I do not believe such granularity exists out of the box.

There is nothing to handle here, IMO. If a user chose to not receive notifications for the application or receive them as an alert instead of a notification or only as a sound - that is his or hers prerogative. You shouldn't do anything about it.